# Headless JS Background task is not running in React-Native

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, kotlin

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import task from './src/task';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';


//AppRegistry.registerComponent('App',()=>App);
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('SomeTaskName', () =>
task
);

package com.convertwebsitetoapp;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.react.HeadlessJsTaskService;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
import com.facebook.react.jstasks.HeadlessJsTaskConfig;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;

public class MyTaskService extends HeadlessJsTaskService {

  @Override
  protected @Nullable HeadlessJsTaskConfig getTaskConfig(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
      return new HeadlessJsTaskConfig(
          "SomeTaskName",
          Arguments.fromBundle(extras),
          5000, // timeout for the task
          false // optional: defines whether or not  the task is allowed in foreground. Default is false
        );
    }
    return null;
  }
}

task.js
module.exports = async (taskData) => {
    console.log('Demo')
    
  };
```

I am new in React-Native. Trying to create an app using headless js in react-native
When i start MyTask service  inside `oncreate` method then
the app is crashing and not opening. And when am registering without component `registerheadlessjs` task then am getting the error as  "`registercompoent` was not called"
Please give me one simple example if anyone has.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Now i am able to start my  headless task but its not running in background. It get stopped when i kill the process.                                                                                                          Any Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Same here, i want to run some javascript code when day change (12:00AM) even application is not running.

Answer (score 0):

```
return new HeadlessJsTaskConfig(
      "SomeTaskName",
      Arguments.fromBundle(extras),
      5000, // timeout for the task
      true// optional: defines whether or not  the task is allowed in foreground. Default is false
    );
```

Change false to true